# View httpd/lighttpd modules that are installed on shared hosting

Tags: apache-2.2, lighttpd, httpd, shared-hosting

I don't have access to the httpd.conf file on this shared host, but I wanted to see which modules are enabled/installed.  Is there a (easy) way to find out without access to the httpd.conf file?  For example, with PHP you can run a file that has phpinfo() in it to get the PHP info.  Anything similar? The web server is lighttpd, which I understand is mostly compatible with apache httpd.

(And yes, I am going to email the hosting support, but it sure would be nice to know for the future)

Answer (score 1):

Lighttpd has similar features, but whoever told you the config files are directly compatible was smoking something. You cannot use `.htaccess` files with lighttpd.

The config files are totally different, and while fastcgi works similarly once you have it working, you CANNOT just drop apache configs into lighttpd and expect them to work.

Pragmatically, you can expect the default set of lighttpd modules to be installed. If you're allowed to directly edit your site conf files, you can explicitly load any module you need there using this syntax:

```
server.modules += ( "mod_access", "mod_rewrite" )
```

In general, you should read through the [lighttpd config docs](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs), paying special attention to the section on [migrating from apache](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/MigratingFromApache).

If the lighttpd server has the status module loaded, you may be able to see which modules are loaded there, if you have access to that url. The thing is, the actual loaded modules DO NOT MATTER AT ALL to you if you don't have access to change the config files. There is nothing you can do with a loaded module if you can't configure your site.

Comment: Holy crap.  Paul, first I want to thank you for your thorough reply.  Secondly, I need to tell you that you are right, I must have been smoking something strong when I posed the question - my question really doesn't make sense!!!

Comment: (continued...) And Frankly I am completely embarrassed.  My question is actually about LiteSpeed web server, not lighttpd (I am red as a tomato).  Please don't ask why I said lighttpd in my question. I don't know why other than the fact that I had been reading up on lighttpd recently (research). Holy crap. Thanks for your awesome reply. I hope it helps somebody at somepoint.

Comment: And your hammer really is awesome

Comment: Well, I suppose that your question does make a lot more sense in the context of LiteSpeed (which I know very little about). I can still strongly recommend Lighttpd as an awesome server, but definitely not quite so wonderful in shared hosting environments. No worries!

Answer (score 1):

If you add mod_status to the lighttpd configuration file

```
server.modules = ( ..., "mod_status", ... )
status.config-url = "/server-config"
```

then the relative URL /server-config will display which modules are loaded.  I used this to cut lighttpd diskspace usage by deleting unused modules from the lib directory.   If mod_status has been enabled by the sysadm of the system you should be able to use this to determine which modules are loaded, including those loaded by default.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
httpd -l         # for static modules
httpd -M         # for shared modules
```

Or on Ubuntu:

```
apache2 -l         # for static modules
apache2 -M         # for shared modules
```